# How to initialise controllers using provider state in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, state

I recently refactored half my app to use the provider pattern and i now have a problem. The main issue is that i need to initialise controllers in the init (e.g. a text controller to have an initial value or the list size of a tab controller)

How am i meant to init Controllers if the data i need has to come from the state in the build method.

For example.

```
// This must go in the build as it requires state
myTabsController = TabController(length: myState.list.length, vsync: this);
```

I'm initialisng the controller every time it builds now... How am i meant to put this in the init but still access the state variables (as there is no context).

I've tried using the afterFirstLayout() callback from the AfterLayoutMixin library but that just causes more problems. Currently with the tab bar it flashes error as no tab initialised for the first frame and then displays properly when the  afterFirstLayout is called and initialises the tab. This seems like a hacky fix

I would like to learn more about how to use this pattern properly and what would be the best solution to this problem.

Feel free to ask me to clarify more. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi! Could you perhaps share a minimal example of how you initialise your app?